# Getting indexOf Javascript array made up of Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to get indexOf on this array?

```
var myArray = new Array(
    {title: "Test1", id: "Header1", html: "Header1", style: "background-color: red; color: white;"});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "indexOf"?  Can you explain the operation you'd like to perform, in other words? There's only one element in the array, so it's index is guaranteed to be zero.

Comment: the one element thing was done just for brevity -- I want to check the index of the id of 'Header1' in myArray.  Since this is kind of an associative array, I wasnt sure how to use the indexOf method that comes with array object.  Looks like I can't.

Comment: Well, it's *not* an associative array - it's just an array; that's the thing.  I don't know of any "indexOf" implementation that allows for a "comparator" function parameter, though that'd be possible.

Comment: i dont understand, the array is containing objects, or this would be an associative array?
difference: array cont. objs.: `new Array({a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'},{a:'d',b:'e',c:'f'})`
associative array is not _array_, this is an obj: `associative = {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to make it work -- but it's not pretty:

```
//Check to see if we are going to a card that should be right or left.
var rightOrLeft = "left";
var destinationIndex = 0;
for(var i=0; i < dynamicPreezeArray.length; i++){
        if (dynamicPreezeArray[i].id == this.text) {
                  destinationIndex = i;
       };
}

if (destinationIndex < currentCarouselIndex) {
         rightOrLeft = "right";
}

preezer.setActiveItem(this.text,{type:'slide',direction: rightOrLeft});
currentCarouselIndex = preezer.getActiveIndex();
```

This was all just to make my Sencha carousel look right when clicking buttons, but now I realize that if someone slides it manually that it wont set the currentCarouselIndex... bleh, this is a lot of work just to make it look a little better.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to do a search for that object, if you have the same reference, sure.

```
var o = {"foo": "bar"};
var a = [o];
alert(a.indexOf(o));
```

But this won't work:

```
alert(a.indexOf({"foo": "bar"}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qtjWm/

Comment: ehh. i wouldn't figured this out by myself!